# Is there a minimum distance required from the bottom of the sink to the outlet?

Tags: plumbing

Is there a minimum required by code from the bottom of the sink to the horizontal PVC outlet that goes into the wall?  I am putting in a utility sink and have the top of the horizontal wall outlet three inches below the bottom of the sink (yes I have a p trap in there

Answer (score 1):

There's a minimum and maximum distance the vent must be from the trap (which is based on pipe diameter), but I've never seen a minimum vertical distance.

[image]

The bottom of the fixture should be above the top of the trap arm, but beyond that, it wouldn't make any difference (this should be obvious, as water doesn't flow up :) ).

Comment: Yeah, I know about vent distances…just wasnt sure if there was a minimum distance of vertical (assuming outlet is below sink bottom of course :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, the [Building regulations only state:](https://www.specifiedby.com/building-regulations/approved-document-h-drainage-waste-disposal#FoulSection1) you should have a depth of 75mm in the U-bend, and that the branch to the main stack can be no more than 4m